# I am getting error when executing flock command

Tags: linux, shell, cron, flock

when I am trying to execute flock through cron job I am getting error.

I am executing

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/flock -n /usr/local/monitor/asdp_cloudwatch/run_asdp0101.sh
```

and I am getting below error

```
/usr/bin/flock: bad number: /usr/local/monitor/asdp_cloudwatch/run_asdp0101.sh
```

Can anyone solve this. Help can be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`flock` needs a lock file and a command to run. You've only specified one argument. I'm assuming that it is the command, so must also specify the command to run. Something like that:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/flock -n /path/to/lockfile /usr/local/monitor/asdp_cloudwatch/run_asdp0101.sh
```

You need to adjust `/path/to/lockfile` of course.

Comment: what to specify in place of /path/to/lockfile  ?

Comment: Are you only trying to prevent 2 instances of the script to run simultaneously? Then any lockfile would suffice, e.g. `/tmp/run_asdp0101.lockfile` or even the script itself.